# Can we show how EM fields transform in different frames?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames

I'm a complete novice at physics but this is something that has puzzled me for a while. In Taylors "Classical Mechanics" he states that he will be "taking the view that the Lorentz equation is an observed fact." The wording in this leads me to believe there is a (mathematical) way to show how EM fields transform in different frames of references. If I'm not wrong, we want $K=\frac{d}{d\tau}mv\gamma=\gamma*F$ to transform like a 4 vector, where $F$ is the Lorentz force. So, is it possible to use Lorentz transforms and Maxwells equations to show how EM fields transform in different frames of reference?

I used the infinite line of charge thought experiment and in the end showed that this example was consistent with relativity, however when considering an arbitrary EM field I'd have no idea where to start.

Im very new at this and its quite hard to wrap my head around but I hope I phrased this question correctly, I appreciate any help!

Comment: [Relativistic form of the Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Relativistic_form_of_the_Lorentz_force)

Comment: [Transformation of the fields between inertial frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#Transformation_of_the_fields_between_inertial_frames)

Comment: The spatial part of the [four-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force) is $\gamma$ *times* the three-force.

Comment: @Ghoster it seems like the Lorentz force being consistent with relativity is that the EM tensor is a tensor. Those two wikipedia links look like they dont do anything to derive this fact or to derive the transformation laws. Without assuming either one is there a way to show that the EM tensor actually behaves like a tensor or to show that the fields actually obey that transformation law?

Comment: Once you get to the covariant form for the equation of motion, $dp^\alpha/d\tau = qF^{\alpha\beta}U_\beta$, I think you can argue that since the left side is a four-vector, and $U_\beta$ is a four-vector, and $q$ is a Lorentz invariant, then $F^{\alpha\beta}$ must be a four-tensor. (One definition of tensors is as multilinear maps.)

Comment: @Ghoster wouldn't that still just be assuming that the Lorentz force is consistent with relativity? Is there perhaps a way to compute what the EM fields would look like in another frame of reference with solely through how the Lorentz transform effects spacetime, then use this to support the idea that its consistent? It feels like a cheat to just assume the Lorentz force transforms like this

Comment: You can compute the electric and magnetic fields of a charge at rest, and the electric and magnetic fields of a charge in uniform motion. Then you can determine how they are related, and get the field transformation that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you're basically asking two questions:
Firstly, you want to know if it is possible to derive the transformation of the fields directly from Maxwell's equations.
And secondly, you want to know how the 4-force works in case of electrodynamics.

About the first point: Since $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$, you will always find a vector potential $\vec A$ such that $\vec B = \vec \nabla \times \vec A$. Since $\vec \nabla \times \vec E + \partial_t \vec B = 0$, $\vec \nabla \times (\vec E + \partial_t \vec A) = 0$, you will always find a "scalar" potential (not scalar in a relativistic sense!) $\phi$ such that $\vec E + \partial_t \vec A = -\vec \nabla \phi$ or $\vec E = - \vec \nabla \phi - \partial_t \vec A$. From now on I'll use $(A^{\mu}) := \left(\begin{array}{c} \phi /c \\ A^x \\ A^y \\A^z \end{array} \right)$ and $(j^\mu) := \left(\begin{array}{c} c \cdot \rho \\ \vec j \end{array} \right)$ with $\rho$ the charge and $\vec j$ the current density. 
If you plug that into the other, inhomogeneous Maxwell equations, you'll get (already in index-form) $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu - \partial^\mu(\partial_\nu A^\nu) = \mu_0 j^\mu$, where $\partial_\mu = \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{c} \partial_t \\ \vec \nabla \end{array} \right)$ and $\partial^\mu = \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{c} \partial_t \\ -\vec \nabla \end{array} \right)$.
But those potentials aren't unique, you can always do a gauge transformation without changing the electric and magnetic field (and therefore also without changing the physics), $A^\mu \rightarrow A^\mu - \partial^\mu \chi$ with some scalar function $\chi$. Especially, it is always possible to find such a $\chi$ so that $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$ (Lorenz gauge). In that case the equation above reduces to $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu = \mu_0 j^\mu$.

Now, finally, assume you have two inertial systems connected by a Lorenz transformation. In both inertial systems you can find an $(A^\mu)$ that satisfies the Lorenz gauge, let's call them ${\tilde A}^\mu$ and ${\tilde A^{'}}^\mu$. Then they satisfy the equations $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu \tilde A^\mu = \mu_0 j^\mu$ and ${\partial_\nu}^{'} {\partial^{'}}^\nu {\tilde A^{'}}^\mu = \mu_0 {j^{'}}^\mu$. In order for charge to be conserved, $j^\mu$ has to be a 4-vector (see basically any book on electrodynamics or classical field theory, if you're interested, I can look for some sources).
Therefore, $\tilde A^\mu$ has to be a 4-vector as well (since $\mu_0$ and $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu$ are scalars). Since $\partial^\mu \chi$ is a 4-vector for scalar $\chi$, $A^\mu$ is a 4-vector in general, as long as you choose the same gauge relative to the Lorenz gauge (that is to say you choose the same $\chi$ with $A^\mu = \tilde A^\mu + \partial^\mu \chi$). This is a necessary restriction because you could basically choose any gauge in a given inertial system, so you would not have any well-defined transformation law for $A^\mu$ if you didn't fix the "relative" gauge between inertial systems. 
Knowing that $A^\mu$ is a 4-vector, it is not difficult to obtain the transformation laws for the fields. You could basically already derive them from the transformation laws for $A^\mu$, but that is a little complicated, it's a lot easier with the field strength tensor $F^{\mu \nu} := \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$.

About the second point: It is actually possible to derive a relativistic "F=ma" only from the requirement that in the non-relativistic limit it reduces to F=ma. You can find that derivation in Weinberg gravitation and cosmology. The basic idea is the following: $m (\frac{d^2}{{d \tau}^2} x^\mu)$ is a 4-vector with the proper time $d \tau = \frac{ds}{c} = dt'$ and $m$ the mass of the particle in its momentary rest frame (there mass can be defined as usually because classical mechanics is exactly correct there, see below), where t' is the time in the momentary rest frame (at every fixed point in time there is an inertial frame in which a given particle is at rest). That follows from the fact that $x^\mu$ is a 4-vector and $d \tau$ is a scalar (or rather the differential of a scalar). Now in the momentary rest frame, where by definition the particle doesn't move and therefore the velocity is infinitely smaller than c - so the non-relativistic limit is exactly correct, F=ma has to count. That means in the momentary rest frame $m (\frac{d^2}{{d \tau}^2} {x^{'}}^\mu) = \left(\begin{array}{c} m d^2 (c t')/{dt'}^2 \\ m {\frac{d^2}{{dt'}^2} \vec x'} \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \vec F_N \end{array} \right)$, where $\vec F_N$ is the Newton force in the momentary rest frame (or alternatively with $\vec v = 0$). Now you can transform back to your original inertial frame (simple Lorentz transformation) and you'll get $m (\frac{d^2}{{d \tau}^2} {x^{'}}^\mu) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \gamma \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec F_N}{c} \\ \gamma \vec F_{N \parallel} + \vec F_{N \perp} \end{array} \right)$, where $\vec F_{N \parallel}$ is the component of the Newton force which is parallel to $\vec v$ and $\vec F_{N \perp}$ is the perpendicular one. 
In the case of electrodynamics we know that $\vec F_N = q (\vec E^{'} + \vec v \times \vec B^{'}) = q \vec E^{'}$, since $\vec v^{'} = 0$. By the transformation laws for the fields (which I derived or rather showed how to derive above) $\vec F_{N \parallel} = q \vec E^{'}_{\parallel} = q \vec E_{\parallel}$ and $\vec F_{N \perp} =q \vec E^{'}_\perp = q \cdot \gamma (\vec E_{\perp} + \vec v \times \vec B)$. This gives you the relativistic equation of motion $m (\frac{d^2}{{d \tau}^2} {x}^\mu) = q F^{\mu \nu} u_\nu$ with $(u^\mu) = (\frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}) = \gamma \left(\begin{array}{c} c \\ \vec v\end{array} \right)$, as you may check or believe me.